# Most efficient delay circuit

Tags: transistors, timer, 555, delay

I am currently trying to design a basic time delay circuit. The circuit's goal is to switch on a BLE beacon (requires 1.8V-3.6V at 1mA) for 3-5 seconds and then switch it off again. My first option was to use a 555 timer, however, due to the fact that the circuit is battery powered (coin cell CR2032) I require something which uses the least amount of power. I thus opted for an n-channel mosfet with a low-side transistor configuration.

- Is this the best, most efficient manner in which I could build a delay circuit?
- If not, what is and why is it more efficient?

Comment: I'd be curious if a ultra low-power microcontroller running on like a 32khz clock and sleeping would be the lowest...

Comment: How often is your device switched on?

Comment: MSP430 can be put to sleep (waking up on a timer on a 32.768kHz clock) on well under 1 uA; that's about 100x less than even a CMOS 555.

Comment: @MadHatter No more than 10 times a day.

Comment: @BrianDrummond thank you I'll have a look into it straight away.

Comment: @Eckaard Would something like [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/321390/38098) be acceptable? The inactivated current is negligible. (An example with part values and running on 5 V is [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/476717/38098).)

Comment: You need a low power MCU, which will sleep for 3-5 sec and get activated for a short time. It gets activated based on an internal timer. The programming might be hard for you. I am a fan of Microchip PIC, which has everything you need and a free compiler(XC8).
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4QdOuG0TZic

Comment: How does it know it is supposed to turn on in the first place? What is the input? This can possibly be done with a simple CMOS logic state machine.

Comment: @mkeith the input is from a push button.

Comment: @CFCBazarcom Thank you for the Youtube video. I have a couple of pic24s which I will try this on. Will the power consumption be less than using only electronic components such as caps, resistors, transistors, etc? If so, is it due to the fact that Capacitors may retain a charge after the power has been removed and get rid of it through leakage?

Comment: The MCU is build specifically for low power consumption. Everything is already inside. Capacitors are one of the biggest losses in all circuits, if you use your own components they will probably be some average ones, which have a lot of voltage drops, current drains and leakage. Timer555 consumes a lot of current.

The MCU has an internal timer, which is not put into sleep, when the timer hits the desired value, the MCU wakes up and performs all actions, then goes to sleep again for a defined time.

Comment: This is from the PIC24 datasheet: sleep curret 150nA, you can read more about sleep here: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/39727a.pdf

Comment: @jonk thanks you for the links. First off, thanks for the in depth explanation! It took me some time to fully understand all the workings but in the end it seems like I understand the concept. I will try and build it within the next week and get back to you on my results.

Comment: @CFCBazarcom thank you very much! I appreciate all the guidance. Last question; will I be able to put the MCU to sleep and have it wake up on an external interrupt in the form of a push button?

Comment: Yes, there are 2 types of interrupts, internal and external. There is no problem for using a button.

Comment: @CFCBazarcom okay perfect, thank you.

Comment: This can definitely be done with something like an RS latch plus maybe one more logic gate. Or, the button could charge a capacitor which turns on a high-side PMOS switch for 5 seconds (idle current zero). But certainly a pic will work and will give you more precise timing and flexibility if you decide to add additional features or requirements later.

Answer (score 2):

Your "beacon" is probably way smarter than you realize (and an NE555 would use way more power than a beacon). BLE chips are actually microcontrollers with a radio frontend – and many of them are user-programmable.

So, this has a simple software solution.

Comment: Marcus, Thank you for your reply. I'm busy working with a JDY-19. Currently I am making use of AT commands to set the major, minor, baud rate, UUID and transmission rate. I have yet been able to actually program the chip otherwise. I used the following data sheet; [link] (https://myosuploads3.banggood.com/products/20181201/20181201013930JDY-19.pdf) Sorry for getting off topic but if you know of a way that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

The following circuit should come close to your specifications. But it probably won't work down to \$1.8\:\text{V}\$. You'll need a different MOSFET if you want to lower the workable voltage down that far. But this basic topology should get you there, though the time period will be dependent upon the rail voltage. But it has almost no leakage current when **OFF**, so that's good as well.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvSGAr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I've established the value of \$R_2\$ on the basis that your load current is \$1\:\text{mA}\$. If you need a lot more, then \$R_2\$ (and probably \$R_3\$) will need to be adjusted, accordingly.

The selection of the **BSS123** is based upon how common the part is and it's low threshold voltage. But it's just an approximation. If you really need lower voltage operation, closer to \$1.8\:\text{V}\$, then you will need to find a different device with a lower threshold voltage.

Comment: Thank you very much @jonk! This is great! I really appreciate the help. 1.8V is perfect and will work just fine.